# I have encounter {% condition %} postgres usage for conditions, but can not find any proper or example documentation

Tags: python, postgresql, if-statement

SELECT * FROM

```
         {% if override_table_condition_py_file_variable %}
            {{ override_table_py_file_function }}
         {% elif some_cache_condition_py_file_variable %}
             sql_table_path1
         {% else %}
             sql_table_path2
```

This is a part of SQL query in a sql file which was called in a py file

I understand what the code is doing but to be honest this is the first time I am seeing such syntax in xx.sql file. Anyone familiar with this can lead me to a good reading. Appreciate!

Comment: You should add tags for the database API, ORM or framework that you are using.

Comment: It looks like a template file from a templating package like jinja2 - the actual SQL would be generated by rendering the template, passing the conditioning variables to the renderer.

Comment: In addition, it is also similar to Django's template syntax. Look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/language/)